# Exit application using a UIAlertController

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller, uicontrol

If a user opens up the application without an internet connection, a window pops up that says a connection is required, and there is an ok button.  I want to the ok button to exit the application.  Here is what I have:

```
if !isConnectedToNetwork(){
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "No Internet", message: "You need an internet connection to use this app", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I am going to use this to exit the app:

```
UIControl().sendAction(Selector("suspend"), to: UIApplication.sharedApplication(), forEvent: nil)
```

I just don't know how to connect it to the OK button above.

Comment: This is what the `handler` parameter is for in `UIAlertAction`.

Comment: Are you using Reachability from Apple? If so, you could display a message on the screen and disable user interaction. When the Internet connection comes back, you can enable user interaction and get rid of the message. In this case, I would use a label rather than an alert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle when user press OK by the following code

```
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,
handler: { (action:UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
   //after user press ok, the following code will be execute
   NSLog("User pressed OK!!")
}))
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't. Apple will reject this (if they see it).

Simply inform the user and add a 'retry' button. The retry button should obviously check the connection again.

To actually answer the question, you have currently set the `handler: nil` on the button action, instead you can actually set a handler and use it to call whatever logic you like.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question. This is a good comment but not an answer to the question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have looked online a bit, is the reason apple will reject this that they would treat it as an app crash?